# Replace MKS with Powershell

Tags: powershell, mks

can anybody please translate these two scripts from MKS into Powershell? i would like to remove MKS from our ETL tools and accomplish this with Powershell but do not have the chops

1)
FileSize=`ls -l $1 | awk '{print $5}'`

if [ $FileSize -ge 100000000 ]; then
split -b 60000000 $1 $1
fi

2)
find $1 -type f -name *.txt -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;

thanks very much
drew

Answer (score 2):

Avoiding using even standard aliases here (eg. can use `dir` or `ls` rather than `Get-ChildItem`):

> 1) FileSize=ls -l $1 | awk '{print $5}'

```
$filesize = (Get-ChildItem $name).Length
```

> if [ $FileSize -ge 100000000 ]; then split -b 60000000 $1 $1 fi

```
if ($filesize -ge 100000000) { ... }
```

(can't recall function of `split`)

> 2) find $1 -type f -name *.txt -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;

```
$t = [datetime]::Now.AddSeconds(-30)
Get-ChildItem -path . -recurse -filter *.txt |
  Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt $t -and $_.PSIsContainer } |
  Remove-Item
```

(Add a `-whatif` to the `Remove-Item` to list what would be deleted without deleting them.)

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Get the size of the file named by `$1`. If the size is more than 100 megabytes, [`split`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/split.1.asp) it into parts of 60 megabytes each.

**MKS**

```mks
FileSize=`ls -l $1 | awk '{print $5}'`

if [ $FileSize -ge 100000000 ]; then
split -b 60000000 $1 $1
fi
```

**PowerShell**

```powershell
function split( [string]$path, [int]$byteCount ) {
  # Find how many splits will be made.
  $file = Get-ChildItem $path
  [int]$splitCount = [Math]::Ceiling( $file.Length / $byteCount )
  $numberFormat = '0' * "$splitCount".Length
  $nameFormat = $file.BaseName + "{0:$numberFormat}" + $file.Extension
  $pathFormat = Join-Path $file.DirectoryName $nameFormat

  # Read the file in $byteCount chunks, sending each chunk to a numbered split file.
  Get-Content $file.FullName -Encoding Byte -ReadCount $byteCount |
    Foreach-Object { $i = 1 } {
      $splitPath = $pathFormat -f $i
      Set-Content $splitPath $_ -Encoding Byte
      ++$i
    }
}

$FileSize = (Get-ChildItem $name).Length

if( $FileSize -gt 100MB ) {
  split -b 60MB $name
}
```

*Notes:* Only the split functionality needed by the question was implemented, and tested just on small file sizes. You may want to look into [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) and [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) to perform more efficient buffered IO.

---

**2)** In the directory named by `$1`, [`find`](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/find.1.asp) all regular files with a `.txt` extension that were modified over thirty days ago, and remove them.

**MKS**

```mks
find $1 -type f -name *.txt -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

**PowerShell**

```powershell
$modifiedTime = (Get-Date).AddDays( -30 )
Get-ChildItem $name -Filter *.txt -Recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $modifiedTime } |
  Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

*Notes:* Take off the `-WhatIf` switch to actually perform the remove operation, rather than previewing it.